# Stored procedure doesn't return records from "all_" system tables

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that needs to iterate through a particular system table to perform some logic based upon the table index fields.

When my stored procedure (existing in my own user schema) iterates through the `all_ind_columns` Oracle system table, no records are returned. 
When my user executes the same select statement manually, I can see the needed data.

I discovered that if I use `dba_ind_columns` within the stored procedure, records are returned.

Why is it that `all_ind_columns` is empty when accessed directly from the stored procedure??

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SQLGEN 
       ( full_table IN VARCHAR2
         , action IN VARCHAR2
        , cols IN VARCHAR2
        , outtext OUT VARCHAR2 )
 AS 

voutput VARCHAR2(32767);
vallindexcolumns VARCHAR2(32767);

CURSOR cursor_index_columns IS
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
       index_name,
       table_owner,
       TABLE_NAME,
       column_position
FROM all_ind_columns
WHERE index_name LIKE '%PRIMARY'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME'
ORDER BY column_position;

curr_record cursor_index_columns%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
FOR curr_record IN cursor_index_columns LOOP 
    vallindexcolumns := 'Output for record now';
END LOOP;

outtext := vallindexcolumns;

END SQLGEN;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be seeing the confluence of two things. The `all_*` tables only show you objects that you have permissions on; and privileges granted through roles are not honoured in [definers-right's stored procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authorization.htm#i1007304).

So if you inherit permissions on tables through a role then you can see those tables in `all_tables` etc. and query them in plain SQL, and can query the tables themselves; but you can't do either within a stored procedure by default.

You can check if that is the issue by doing `set role none` and reissuing the plain SQL query; it will no longer return anything.

You can change the procedure definition so the calling user's roles are honoured:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SQLGEN 
       ( full_table IN VARCHAR2
         , action IN VARCHAR2
        , cols IN VARCHAR2
        , outtext OUT VARCHAR2 )
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS
...
```

Your permissions on the `dba_*` views must have been granted directly to your user, not through a role; and those views show all objects, not just those you have permissions on.

Comment: Ah I think that makes sense. After I executed 'set role none,' you are right, I couldn't see any records in all_ind_columns (for the current session). From within the procedure, I added 'AUTHID CURRENT_USER'. No luck in getting that to work yet