# Loop block in stored procedure not getting executed

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have created the following PL/SQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "REF_COPY_DB"()
AS
   concept varchar2(10000);
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('hello test 1');
    FOR concept IN (
        SELECT
            table_name
        FROM
            all_tables
        WHERE
                owner = 'WLCR_DEV08'
            AND table_name LIKE '%_REF'
            AND table_name IN (
'CURRENCY_ROLE_WS_REF')
  
    ) LOOP
       
        dbms_output.put_line('hello test 2'); -- not getting printed
       
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And executing it with the statement: `call ref_copy_db()`

I see the following under the `script output`-> `hello test 1    call completed` and `dbms output` window -> `hello test 1`

The procedure is called from the `WLCR_DEV02` DB.  The `hello test 2` is not getting printed. Not sure why that could be happening. Because I ran the inner statement on `WLCR_DEV02`

```
SELECT
    table_name
FROM
    all_tables
WHERE
    owner = 'WLCR_DEV08'
    AND table_name LIKE '%_REF'
    AND table_name IN ('CURRENCY_ROLE_WS_REF')
```

and the script output window does print out the following:

```
TABLE_NAME  
--------------------
CURRENCY_ROLE_WS_REF
```

That means the loop has data to iterate over. But for some reason, it's not going inside the loop block, and probably due to that the DBMS output line is not getting printed.
What could be the reason for this? Any ideas to debug this?

Comment: If `WLCR_DEV02` has grants for table mentioned through roles, this grants are not applied in plsql blocks. Roles are considered "too dynamic" for plsql.

Comment: Does it compile with brackets `()`? [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RwK1cO0H)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be erroring, it just isn't going into the loop, so it can't see the expected table - which is almost certainly a role-granted privilege issue (`WLCR_DEV02` has select against the tables owned by `WLCR_DEV08` granted through a role, not directly, as markalex said).

Comment: So probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24540706/266304) and others, but OP can confirm how privileges were granted.

Comment: @markalex @Alex So I read that privileges granted to roles don't apply inside PL/SQL. In that case are there any specific `GRANT` commands I could run to make this work? or what's the ideal solution to make the pl/SQL stored procedure work

Comment: @nick, you need directly grant select on the mentioned table to the owner of a function: `GRANT SELECT ON WLCR_DEV08.CURRENCY_ROLE_WS_REF to WLCR_DEV02 `.

Comment: Or use `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` as shown in the linked question. You can decide which approach is more suitable for your situation.

Comment: @markalex Thanks a lot that worked. But what if I have to loop over say 50 such tables? Using a GRANT SELECT on each of them could be effortful. Any alternative you suggest here in that case? Later on, I don't just intend to select the tables but also insert data into them

Comment: Try Alex's suggestion, If I understand correctly (which is not granted, I'm afraid I'm out of my depth with Oracle here), it should work with roles.

Comment: @markalex Yeah adding `authid current_user` works. That solves my issue. So we have this simple way of adding one line `authid current_user` and other where I do a `GRANT` for everything. If I use the `authid` approach does it have any cons? Can I use it in production? or what's the best practice in this case?

Comment: @AlexPoole Would you suggest using `authid current_user` in prod? Are there any disadvantages to using this approach that I should be aware of? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also since the privileges from the role don't take effect in a stored procedure, why doesn't the procedure mentioned in the OP throw any error or exception? It just stops silently

Comment: There's some discussion [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/managing-security-for-definers-rights-and-invokers-rights.html#GUID-547A6A16-51AA-4FD9-BDB9-0D8A79B8CF24). There's no error in the procedure. The issue isn't with being able to query `all_tables`; it's that that query returns no data. You can see the same thing if you run the query manually (and will see the tables), then do `set role none` and run it again (and you won't see the tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can start to debug the issue by checking how many rows match in the procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "REF_COPY_DB"()
AS
  v_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('hello test 1');

  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   v_count
  FROM   all_tables
  WHERE  owner = 'WLCR_DEV08'
  AND    table_name LIKE '%_REF'
  AND    table_name IN ('CURRENCY_ROLE_WS_REF');

  dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
END;
/
```

If you find that you are getting 0 rows or an exception then you can look deeper.

- Does the user running the procedure have access to the `ALL_TABLES` view?
- As mentioned by @markalex, does the `WLCR_DEV08` user only have access to the `ALL_TABLES` view through granted roles? In which case the procedure will not have access as it will not apply permissions from roles.
- Has someone create an `ALL_TABLES` table or view owned by the `WLCR_DEV08` user that is shadowing the `SYS.ALL_TABLES` view? In which case, try `SELECT ... FROM SYS.ALL_TABLES ...`
- Does your SQL have invisible characters in the string literals that are preventing the filters from matching?
- Etc.

Comment: Grants are not needed to ALL_TABLES, public always has select privs on ALL_* views. But internally ALL_* views will filter out objects in its output data that the auth user doesn't have any privs to, so it could be a lack of directly granted select privs on the WLCR_DEV08.CURRENCY_ROLE_WS_REF table.